# Java youngest and oldest in an array of n

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a program to find the oldest and youngest person based on the ages and names that I have entered. The problem is, the program only gives me the oldest person, the else if statement for the youngest doesn't execute.

```
public class Boo {

public static void main(String[] strings) {

  int[] age = new int[10];
  String[] name = new String[10];
  int count = 0;

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  boolean notDone = true;

  int smallest = age[0];
  int largest = age[0];

  String smalName = "";
  String larName = "";


do {


  System.out.println("Enter name");
  name[count] = in.next();



  if (!name[count].equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
    System.out.println("Enter age");
    age[count] = in.nextInt();

    if (age[count] > largest) {
      largest = age[count];
      larName = name[count];
    }
    else if (age[count] < smallest) {
      smallest = age[count];
      smalName = name[count];
    }

  }
  else if (name[count].equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
    notDone = false;
  }

  count++;

}while(notDone && count < 3);
```

Comment: `if (age[count] < smallest) {` without else

Comment: you start with `smallest = age[0]`, `age[0]` is initialize to `0`, so you will always find `0`. A good way to prevent this is to put the max an min value of the type. Here `smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE` AND `largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: thanks, its working.

Comment: By the way, `else if (name[count].equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {` that check is not necessary since you already know it is **not** `!name[count].equalsIgnoreCase("done"))` from the `if`. You can just `else { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Your `smallest` variable is being instantiated to `0`, because you set it to `age[0]`, which being an array of integers has already been initialized to their default values of 0.

Try setting it to `age[0]` after you've first taken an age as an input, and then comparing subsequently.

```
int smallest = age[0];
int largest = age[0];
do
{
  System.out.println("Enter name");
  name[count] = in.next();
  if (!name[count].equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
  {
    System.out.println("Enter age");
    age[count] = in.nextInt();

    if (count == 0)
    {
      smallest = age[0];
      largest = age[0];
      larName = name[0];
      smalName = name[0];
    }
    else
    {
      if (age[count] > largest)
      {
        largest = age[count];
        larName = name[count];
      }
      if (age[count] < smallest)
      {
        smallest = age[count];
        smalName = name[count];
      }
    }
  }
  else if (name[count].equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
  {
    notDone = false;
  }

  count++;

} while (notDone && count < 3);
```

Comment: This is over complicated. Put the limit of the value for each `Integer.[MIN|MAX]_VALUE` to begin with and you can remove those `if(count ==0`... This will get the name for the first unput (unless you input the min or max value, but this is unlikely on that case).

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's best practice to separate it into 2 methods - one to get the youngest and on for the eldest. It will be clear to other developers who will might look at your code.
If that's not an option, you can use Pair in order to return two values. It meant to be for key and value but it enables you to return 2 values.

Comment: It's inefficient to iterate through the same data twice. Of course in this example the data will be too tiny for it to matter, but it's a good learning exercise to do as much as you can in a single traversal through the data.

Comment: ... and there are situations where you *can't* look at the data twice, e.g. when streaming.

Comment: the best practice is to use methods to do the min/max checks, not to iterate the full list. For the reasons, see the previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has some quirks that, maybe, you are not aware of. Your array age has been initialized by default. If you know what you are doing, it is not necessarily bad, but in this case it seems that you didn't. You are initializing the value of smallest and largest with values that are not in your list.

My advice is that you separate the recording of values from the computation of values.

EDIT: I mean something in this terms.

```
private class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}

private Person enterPerson(Scanner sc) {
    Person person = null;
    String name = sc.next();
    if(name != "done) {
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        person = new Person();
        person.name = name;
        person.age = age;
    } 
    return person;
}

private Person youngest(List<Person> list) {
    Person youngest = null;
    for(Person person: list) {
        if(youngest == null || youngest.age > person.age) {
             youngest = person;
        }
    }
    return person;
}

// Oldest would be equivalent
```